# Can too many devices on one USB-C port damage the port

Tags: usb, external-disk

First of all, I know what I had was not a good setup so I changed it. I had two external USB 3.0 2.5" HDDs permanently connected to an passive USB HUB for a long time. Neither the HUB nor the drive had an external power adapter. For TimeMachine I added a third one, which worked fine for two days. After two days I ran into trouble, since the drives needed more power then the port could deliver. One of the drives sometimes made clicking sounds and could get activated. Of course, I immediately removed one of the drives (after shutting down) and replaced the HUB with an active one. In the beginning one of the drives was incorrectly removed (without pulling it's plug), but after that it worked fine again for some days. Still I feel a bit unsafe about this and removed the drives and the HUB. Currently I only have one drive connected at the same time(, but I would like to have at least two connected). Neither the drive nor the USB-C port (on my MBP14 2021) show any signs of damage. I have some questions:

1. Is it safe to connect three drives simultaneously using an active USB-HUB
2. I bought an USB-C ammeter. Is it safe to plug this between the HUB and my MBP to check that the mA do not exceed 900 (what other parameters should I check)?
3. Can this situation have damaged my USB-C port in any way and if yes, how could I check this?